# MYSQL grouping by field that is not null

Tags: mysql, grouping

I have a table where a field is populated if the record is a duplicate. The code is already running, and properly checks for duplicates and is working.

The table looks like this:

```
 id  | dupe_ids | id_subscription
  1       NULL         5343
  2       3, 4         5343
  3       2, 4         5343
  4       2, 3         5343
  5       NULL         5343
  6        7           5343
  7        6           5343
```

The query should return a count for the number of entries, but needs to group the duplicated ids. I need the query to group the records that have entries into one count, but somehow based on the duplicates. In the example above the count for subscription 5343, the count would be 4. Record 2 would count as one with 3 and 4 being skipped or grouped, and record 6 would count as one, with record 7 being grouped or skipped.

The query now looks like this:

```
SELECT app.id_subscription, app.id_site, app.id_customer, COUNT(*) AS app_count, site.url
FROM web_manager.app, web_manager.site
WHERE app.id_customer = :wm_id
AND (app.received_at BETWEEN :sdate AND :edate)
AND app.id_site = site.id
AND app.dupe_ids IS NULL
GROUP BY app.id_subscription
ORDER BY app_count DESC
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I think the question is "What SQL statement canst and shalt I execute against this Monty Python-esque table to get a count of 3 returned"... `And the LORD spake, saying, "First shalt thou take out the Holy Pin, then shalt thou count to three, no more, no less. Three shall be the number thou shalt count, and the number of the counting shall be three. Four shalt thou not count, neither count thou two, excepting that thou then proceed to three. Five is right out.`

Comment: Just change `AND app.dupe_ids IS NULL` to `AND app.dupe_ids IS NOT NULL`. Then you'll get the correct count.

Comment: Sorry about not being more precise with my question. I am going to update my question and look through the answers. Thanks!

Comment: This question serves as a good example of why we strongly recommend *avoiding* "comma separated lists" of values. This would be much more straightforward if we weren't dealing with that... if we had some *other* way of identifying duplicates, like storing foreign key references in a second table, or some conditions/criteria, so we could use SQL to evaluate a set. String parsing and manipulation is really not the strong suit of SQL.

Comment: @spencer7593 I will look and see what other fields there are to filter on. Probably first and last name, and phone number (which is what I think the dupe_ids are based). The database is pre-existing, and has about 3.5 million records, so I can't change the structure, but can probably base it on other field(s).

Answer (score 0):

If the values in `dupe_ids` is a list of numeric `id` values, and the list is always "in order" with the lowest value being the first in the list, as a dirty solution...

The query in my original answer (below) modified to replace the constant `0` with an expression like this: `LEAST(a.id,SUBSTRING_INDEX(a.dupe_ids,',',1)+0)`.

That expression is saying: take the first value from the `dupe_ids` list, evaluate it in a numeric context, compare the numeric value to the `id` value from the row, and return the lower of the two.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT IF(a.dupe_ids IS NULL,a.id,LEAST(a.id,SUBSTRING_INDEX(a.dupe_ids,',',1)+0))) AS my_funky_cnt
     , a.id_subscription
  FROM web_manager.app a
  JOIN web_manager.site s
    ON s.id = a.id_site
 WHERE ...
 GROUP BY a.id_subscription
```

ORDER BY my_funky_cnt DESC

Again, removing the `GROUP BY` and the aggregate, to see what is actually being returned by the expression...

```
 SELECT a.id
      , a.dupe_ids
      , a.id_subscription
      , IF(a.dupe_ids IS NULL,a.id,LEAST(a.id,SUBSTRING_INDEX(a.dupe_ids,',',1)+0)) AS expr
   FROM web_manager.app a
   JOIN web_manager.site s
     ON s.id = a.id_site
  WHERE ...
  ORDER BY a.id_subscription, a.dupe_ids IS NULL, a.id
```

we'd expect that to return:

```
  id  | dupe_ids | id_subscription | expr
   2       3, 4         5343          2       -- id=2 is less than fv=3
   3       2, 4         5343          2       -- fv=2 is less than id=3
   4       2, 3         5343          2       -- fv=2 is less than id=4
   6        7           5343          6       -- id=6 is less than fv=7
   7        6           5343          6       -- fv=6 is less than id=7
   1       NULL         5343          1
   5       NULL         5343          5
```

So a `GROUP BY id_subscription` and `COUNT(DISTINCT expr)` would return a count of 4.

(this not tested)

This approach depends on `dupes_id` having the lowest id value listed first (first value in the list), evaluating that first value in a numeric context, and comparing that to the `id` value from the row.

If `dupe_ids` is an empty string, or starts with a comma, or the first non-blank characters can't be interpreted as a numeric value, then `expr` is going to return a `0`.

**EDIT**

The original answer (below) was based on collapsing all of the rows with non-NULL values for a given id_subscription... returning a count of 3.  The question has been updated, adding more example rows with non-NULL values which should not be collapsed together. Desired return for "count" is now 4. The query in the original answer would return a count of 3.

Getting a count of rows with a NULL value of `dupe_ids` is straightforward.

The sticky wicket is the bizarre contents of the `dupe_ids` column, the comma separated list of id values...

```
 id    dupe_ids
 ----  --------
 2     '3,4'
 3     '2,4'
 4     '2,3'
 6     '7'
 7     '6'
```

This would be easier if we weren't dealing with a "comma separated list" of values. If we instead had foreign key references to the rows, in a separate table. Or, if we had some criteria other than the `dupe_ids` columns to identify rows that are "duplicates".

But, this wasn't the question asked. The question didn't ask if it would be better to *avoid* storing a comma separated list; whether there was a better approach.

The question leaves us dealing with a comma separated list. (It serves as an example of why we strongly recommend avoiding comma separated lists in the first place).

If we had an expression that has the values in `dupe_ids` along with the `id` value, together, so that we had *identical* values on the rows...

```
id    dupe_ids  expr
----  --------  ------
2     '3,4'     '2,3,4'
3     '2,4'     '2,3,4'
4     '2,3'     '2,3,4'
6     '7'       '6,7'
7     '6'       '6,7'
```

Then we could use a `COUNT(DISTINCT expr)` to get us the return we're after. The ugly part is getting that value of `expr`. It would be easy to prepend or append `id` onto `dupe_ids`, but the resulting string values wouldn't be identical. The lists would be in a different order.

There's no simple builtin in function in MySQL to return the values shown for `expr` based on the contents of `id` and `dupe_ids`.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

The approach I would take is to use an expression, and count distinct values of that.

If `dupe_ids` is null, the return a unique value. If `id` is unique in the table, I would just use the value of that column. If `dupe_ids` is not null, then substitute a constant that is not a valid `id` value. Assuming `id` values are positive integers, I would use 0 or a negative value.

As an example:

```
 SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT IF(a.dupe_ids IS NULL,a.id,0)) AS my_funky_cnt
      , a.id_subscription
   FROM web_manager.app a
   JOIN web_manager.site s
     ON s.id = a.id_site
  WHERE ...
  GROUP BY a.id_subscription
  ORDER BY my_funky_cnt DESC
```

I'd verify the expression is "working" by first doing a query without the GROUP BY and aggregate...

```
 SELECT a.id
      , a.dupe_ids
      , a.id_subscription
      , IF(a.dupe_ids IS NULL,a.id,0) AS derived_col
   FROM web_manager.app a
   JOIN web_manager.site s
     ON s.id = a.id_site
  WHERE ...
  ORDER BY a.id_subscription, a.dupe_ids IS NULL, a.id
```

We'd expect that to return:

```
  id  | dupe_ids | id_subscription | derived_col
   1       NULL         5343          1
   2       3, 4         5343          0
   3       2, 4         5343          0
   4       2, 3         5343          0 
   5       NULL         5343          5
```

So all of the rows with non-null `dupe_ids` have the same value, and the rows with NULL `dupe_ids` have a unique value.

And a `COUNT(DISTINCT` of that expression will return 3.

Comment: You understood his question?

Comment: @Barmar: Not at first. The only way I could get a count of 3 was to "collapse" all of the rows with non-NULL values for `dupe_id` into a single row. (I need to check Bill Karwin's book to see if there was a chapter on this anti-pattern.)

Comment: Doesn't that just come from `AND dupe_ids IS NOT NULL` in his query?

Comment: I updated the question. After reading the comments, and looking at the example I realized that the example was not detailed enough, because there will be duplicates that need to be grouped based on the other duplicates, and not ALL duplicates should be grouped into one.

Comment: @spencer7593. After digging through the files, I have found that duplicates are marked based on email address and phone. Phone may be NULL, but I may be able to use email, using your 'derived_col' above.

Comment: @Judson: "**`LEAST(a.id,SUBSTRING_INDEX(a.dupe_ids,',',1)+0)`**" might do the trick, with some strict caveats and conditions. (answer is edited).

Comment: @spencer7593 This solution is getting closer, but some records are being counted more that one, I think due to there being no sequence to the dupe_ids. Also, since this is for date range reporting some duplicates are being counted for apps outside the date range. This wasn't part of the original question, but as I run the queries I see this problem.